# SSIS connecting to CRM OData endpoint dtd error

Tags: ssis, odata, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to use the [SSIS OData Source component](http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=42280) to connect to the [CRM OData Endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx), but it's giving me the following error:

> For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method. (System.Xml)

Has anyone got this working before? Any tricks to prevent it from doing the DTD check?

The XML the service responds starts as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<service xml:base="https://url.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">
```

Comment: Ok, it appears that this is down to authentication - something to do with claims based authentication mucking it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is that the SSIS OData Connection won't do the OAuth dance, and as such fails to cope with CRM.

What I did instead was use the [RSSBus CRM component](http://www.rssbus.com/download/) to connect.

Answer (score 1):

playing with

- crm online
- azure active directory
- ssis
- C# (script component)
- xml transformation

you can achieve it. Our company created a blog post for that.
sorry for not posting the whole solution here, it's kind of long

[Part 1](https://stuffandtacos.azurewebsites.net/2016/03/24/use-crm-dynamics-online-odata-endpoints-in-ssis/)
[Part 2](https://stuffandtacos.azurewebsites.net/2016/03/24/use-crm-dynamics-online-odata-endpoints-in-ssis-part2/)

Comment: Thanks for this - I'll take a read through this when I can concentrate properly and I might edit some of it into your answer - from a skim it looks like a really good post, thanks.